# Refresh part of page with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I can't update my label with Jquery. It should update after every second on my page but nothing happens. Is there something wrong with my javascript?

Basically what I want to do is update the label every second. But somehow this isn't working. Can anyone please help me out?

Below you can find the code for my 2 files:

//////////////  Index.html:  /////////////////

```
<!--AWP_IN_Variable Name='"webdata".AmountOfErrors' -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
   <title>Gebr. Gerrits Recycling Helmond</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Maindiv">
        <div class="header">
           <img src="images/gerritslogo800.jpg" class="Logo">   
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <br/>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Part</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ferro:</td>
            <td>0 kg</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Non-Ferro:</td>
            <td>0 kg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Errors:</td>
            <td><label id="amountOfErrors" name="amountOfErrors">:="webdata".AmountOfErrors:</label></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //query the amountOfErrors variable every second
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function() 
        {
            $.get("IOamountOfErrors.htm", function(result)
            {
                $('#amountOfErrors').text(result);
            });
        },1000);
    });
</script>
       <div class="footer">
           Gebr. Gerrits Metaalhandel Helmond B.V. <br/>
           Gebr. Gerrits Metaalrecycling B.V. <br/>
           Auto Verschrotings Industrie "A.V.I." Den Bosch B.V. <br/>
           Euregio Recycling B.V.<br/>      
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//////////////  IOamountOfErrors.htm:  /////////////////

< !-- AWP_IN_Variable Name='"webdata".AmountOfErrors' -->
:="webdata".AmountOfErrors:
(added the space between '<' and '!' else it wouldn't show the code on this site)

Already searched the net for this: I actually found the same stuff that I needed but for me it isn't working: https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

My best would be that you're debugging this local and not on a webserver right?

Because your javascript is trying to do a cross origin requests which doesn't work on file://

EDIT:

Can you try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //query the amountOfErrors variable every second
        setInterval(function() 
        {
            $.post("IOamountOfErrors.htm", function(result)
            {
                $('#amountOfErrors').text(result);
            });
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well I can't read the variable in a local environment since it's a PLC(programmable logic controller) webserver. I need to update only that part of my page. The variable changes when I press the f5 button but that's not what I want...

Comment: @Bart are you sure you copied everything? The problem with your javascript is that you are using a get with cachign set to false. Ajax will just add chars to the end of your url but the error was that it couldn't find the URL because of those chars. You should remove ajaxSetup and instead of making a get request you should do a post reuqest because those aren't cached

Comment: I copied your part and placed it over my script. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well to update your label you can use setInterval. Here's Code which might be useful

```
var count = 20;
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){  startCounter() }, 1000);
}
$("#counterStart").click(function(e){
    myFunction();
});
 function startCounter() {
    $("#counter").text(count);
 }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="counter" id="counterStart"  />
<span id="counter">dfsdfs </span>
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishkumar9211/60s4nzva/)

Comment: Well i can see @owain has already added that  Check your $.post("IOamountOfErrors.htm", function(result) something is wrong in it